# How to download files from google drive using gmail addon which is created using App script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, card

I'm using **card services** to make a **Gmail addon**. I am **creating a pdf file** of my current email and **uploading it on Google Drive**. I want to **develop a download feature** on button clicks. When the user clicks the Button, **I** **want to download the email as a pdf from Google Drive**.

Can anyone guide me on downloading files from Google Drive using the Gmail addon created in App Script?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. The only part you are missing is a button to download files from Apps Script to the computer? Are the PDF files stored in a specific folder in Google Drive? Do they have a specific name?

Comment: Yes, the PDF files are stored in a specific folder and files have a specific name. I want to download that specific file from google drive using the Gmail addon which is created using the app script.

Comment: You can get the file and use the method `getDownloadUrl()`, you can read more information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl)